# How to count all multiple cells in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to count All the multiple colors assigned for one project in Excel column. I tried the below formula but its counting the only value which I requested. `=COUNTIFS(C10:C17, G19, E10:E17, H19)`.

```
**Project List      Colors**
Project a           Black 
Project b           Brown 
Project c           Red 
Project d           Orange 
Project a           Yellow 
Project b           Brown 
Project c           Red 
Project e           Black 
Project f           Green
```

In the above table, if selected a cell contain Project a, it should display 1 Black and 1 Yellow. If selected a cell contain project b, it should display 2 brown.

Edit: Colors are values its not a actual color or background color.

Comment: There is a lot of ambiguity in your question. Firstly, are the colours an actual cell value or is it the background/font colour? Aslo you have shown a formula that does not relate to the example data provided, you will need to provide more example data or explain what kind of data the formula is referencing. Lastly you mention showing the cell colours for the selected cell, do you mean the cell that is physically selected or a cell that is being referenced?

Comment: Colors are actual cell value. Its not any background color. If we enter Project a in a black cell, the result should count the numbers of colors assigned to that project. like for project a it is 1 Black and 1 Yellow.

Comment: You can do that with a Pivot Table.  And you can select individual projects, if need be, with a Filter

Comment: There is no formula to achieve this. I want to make automatic sheet to distribute to staff.

Comment: `COUNTIFS` is not designed to return text results. It will return a number. Probably `INDEX` based array formula can be suggested if you clarify your data layout.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij, please let me know if you need any more information. I want to achieve this. I have provided all the information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UDF

```
Function modifiedCountif(Rng1 As Range, Criteria1 As Range, Rng2 As Range)
Dim i As Long
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Dim Result As String

Result = ""
For i = 1 To Rng1.Count
    If Rng1.Cells(i, 1) = Criteria1 Then
    On Error Resume Next
        dict.Add Rng2.Cells(i, 1).Value, Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Rng1, Criteria1, Rng2, Rng2.Cells(i, 1))
    End If
Next

Dim key As Variant
For Each key In dict.Keys
    Result = Result & dict(key) & " " & key & ", "
Next key

modifiedCountif = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 2)
dict.RemoveAll
End Function
```

Where `Rng1` is the range of *Project List*

`Criteria1` is the project you are searching for.

`Rng2` is the Range for *colors*

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your actual data ranges so following is my test setup.

- Project List is in range `C10:C18`.
- Colors List is in range `E10:E18`.
- Input cell which holds a single value like `Project b` is `I2`.

Then formula will be (to be committed by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> simultaneously while in edit mode. If applied correctly, Excel will wrap formula by {}).

`=IFERROR(INDEX($E$10:$E$18,SMALL(IF($C$10:$C$18=$I$2,IF(MATCH($C$10:$C$18&$E$10:$E$18,$C$10:$C$18&$E$10:$E$18,0)=(ROW($E$10:$E$18)-9),ROW($E$10:$E$18),2097153),2097153),ROWS($A$1:A1))-9),"")`

You will have to adjust the ranges to suit. Attention must be given to number 9 which is used because data starts at row 10. It should be always (n-1) assuming n is row where your data begins!